# Topology on upper semicontinuous functions and Baire one functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Which is the standard topology on upper semicontinuous functions and on functions of Baire class one, in both cases defined on a compact real interval?

Comment: Topology on the graph of these functions?

Comment: If you restrict to bounded functions then the uniform norm would seem pretty natural, since unless I'm mistaken it would make both spaces complete.